# Two level settings menu with reusable tableview for iOS

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, code-reuse

I am very new to iOS App development and need some help. I am trying to implement a settings kind of screen where some of the items will display more options in the next screen. Trying nested two level settings for now.

I am trying to use a `UITableView` but have not been able to reuse the same for displaying the next level of options. I am trying to avoid rewriting the same piece of code here.

Does anybody have suggestions for this? Thanks.

**Here is the code:**

```
class SettingsMenuViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {

    @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!

    var Options = ["Settings1", "Settings2", "Settings3" ]


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        tableView.delegate = self
        tableView.dataSource = self
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return Options.count
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = UITableViewCell()
        cell.textLabel!.text = Options[indexPath.row]
        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryType.disclosureIndicator
        return cell
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        let cell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath)
        switch cell?.textLabel?.text {
        case "Settings1"?:
        //On selecting this option, need to load new set of setting options which are relevant to Settings1 but want to reuse the tableView available here

        case "Settings2"?:


        case "Settings3"?:


        case "Settings4"?:



        default:

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Show your code to understand what is exactly the problem

Comment: Added the code. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you want to reuse code then you should push SettingsMenuViewController object (new Object not self) with Options values at table didSelectRowAt like:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    let cell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath)
    switch cell?.textLabel?.text {
    case "Settings1"?:
       let vc = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "SettingsMenuViewController") as! SettingsMenuViewController
       vc.Options = ["Settings5","Settings6"]
       self.navigationController?.pushViewController(vc, animated: true)

    case "Settings2”?:


    case "Settings3”?:


    case "Settings4”?:



    default:

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you are trying to use the same tableView to display both levels of the settings page.

Changing the datasource will always update the cell contents. Hence you can use this to simulate the changes in the table in the following place:

```
optional func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath)
```

Just change the datasource to the appropriate one in the above delegate method. (Make sure that the new datasource objects is compatible with how you access them in **func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell**)

Comment: Using @Janit solution will also provide the transition effect fyi